# How is an input like 123cplusplus a valid integer when read with cin?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int val;

    if(cin>>val)
        cout<<"Valid Input"<<" "<<val<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Invalid input"<<" "<<val<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If i am giving the input an integer
like 123 then the condition inside if is true and it works fine and if i am giving a string or a character
as an input then the else part is working fine .But if i am giving an input like 123cplusplus then it is printing valid
input but 123cpluscplus is not an integer . why?

when i am giving an invalid input then it is printing the value of variable "val" equals to 0.Since the val is not initialized in the program then how it gets value 0 after reading invalid input ?

Comment: *"but 123cpluscplus is a string"* and "123" is also a string. When you read from a character stream, you are always reading a string.

Answer (score 5):

When it reads in `123cplusplus` it'll read in `123` into the number `val`, then it'll realize that it's not a number anymore and will leave `cpluscplus` in the input stream.

Comment: Supporting information: [Documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: thanks.one more doubt i have .since you are saying that it is realizing that it is not a number anymore then it should make the condition false inside if and execute else part?

Comment: @AbhinavRaj you need to think in terms of the stream. To you 123cplusplus  is a single string. To the stream it's a 1 followed by a 2 followed by a 3 followed by a c.... If you need 123cplusplus to be rejected, you'll need to tell the stream to read it as a string until a delimiter is reached and then use a tool that will consider the entire string and reject if it's not not entirely comprised of valid digits.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the val is not initialized in the program then how it gets value 0 after reading invalid input ?

Since `val` is not initialised, it has an indeterminate value. If an indeterminate value is produced by an expression, the behaviour of the program is undefined <sub>(there are some exceptions which do not apply here)</sub>. In your `else` branch `val` has an indeterminate value when you insert it to the output stream. In that case the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input into a string, and verify does input has anything other than number, you would get correct result.

```
    std::string input;

    cin >> input;

    if(  std::all_of( input.begin(), input.end(), 
        []( unsigned char c ) { return std::isdigit( c ) ; } ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Valid Input " << input << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input " << input << std::endl;
    }
```

[`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of) check if predicate returns true for all elements.